# Problem in if and {endif} and {endwhile} in my first Project?

Tags: php

This problem in php I need solution in this day
Please for my homework

Can you help me in my homework please because I'm not working but I'm reading in my university Please can you solve this problem.

Can you explain to my this problem or can connection to my desktop to solution this problem or can send explain .

This code

`index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php require_once 'process.php'?>
<?php 

if(isset ($_SESSION['message']));?>

<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
<?php

echo $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message']);

// and this problem !
<?php endif ?>
?>
<div class="contener">
<?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'rootroot','crudcrud') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FORM data") or die($mysqli->error);

?>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>usernames</th>
            <th>Passowrds</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            <tr>
</thead>
</div>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row ['username'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['password'];?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"
            class="btn btn-info">edit</a>
            <a hraf="process.php?delete=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"
            class="btn btn-danger">
        </td>

</tr>
//this problem !
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>


<?php
function pre_r( $arry ){
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo'</pre>';

}
?>

  <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto">

 <form action="process.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value=" <?php echo $id ?> "
 <br><br><div class="card">

 <div class="card-header bg-dark">
 <h1 class="text-white text-center">  Insert Operation </h1>
 </div><br>

  <label> Username: </label>
 <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value=" <?php echo $username; ?> " placeholder="Enter Your Username"> <br>

  <label> Password: </label>
 <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" value=" <?php echo $password; ?> " placeholder="Password"> <br>
     <?php
     if ($update == true)
     ?>
          <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="update"> update </button>
     <?php else: ?>
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save"> Submit </button>

// and this problem !
     <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

code

```
process.php

=======================================================

    <?php 
    session_start();

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'rootroot','crudcrud') or
        die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    $id = 0;
    $update = false;
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    if (isset ($_POST['save'])){
        $usernames = $_POST['username'];
        $passwords = $_POST['password'];

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO data (username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')") or
            die($mysqli->error);

        $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been saved!";
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success!";

        header('loocation: index.php');

    }
    if (isset ($_GET['delete'])){
        $id = $_GET['delete'];
        $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM data WHERE id=$id") or
        die($mysqli->error());
        SESSION['message'] = "Record has been deleted!";
        SESSION['msg_type'] = "denger!";
        header('loocation: index.php');
    }
    if (isset ($_GET['edit'])){
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = true;
        $result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM data WHERE id=$id") or
        die($mysqli->error());

    if (count($result)==1){
     $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['update'])){

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET username='$username', password='$password' WHERE id=$id") or
        die($mysqli->error);

        $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been Update!";
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning!";

        header('loocation: index.php');

    }
```

Comment: It's clear, it's clear there are a few syntax errors.  `<?php endif; ?>` and `if(isset ($_SESSION['message'])):`  Colon not semi-colon, and your missing a closing `?>` before the endif.  That's just what I see glancing at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece is completely wrong:

```
if(isset ($_SESSION['message']));?>  //<-- : not ;

<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
<?php

echo $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message']);

//<-- no closing tag
<?php endif ?> //<-- missing ;
```

Should be:

```
if(isset ($_SESSION['message'])):?>

<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
<?php

echo $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message']);

endif; ?>
```

It get's pretty ugly when you use a lot of PHP and HTML in the same file, it might be time to look at using a template engine.